# Read text file into 2D double array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I have the following text file.

```
289,112,287,112,286,110,285,110,282,109,280,109,278,109,275,108,273,108,271,106,269,106,266,106,264,106,261,105,258,105,257,105,255,105,254,104,253,104,251,104,249,104,248,104,245,104,244,104,240,104,238,104,235,104,232,104,228,106,226,106,222,107,221,108,216,111,214,111,211,114,209,115,205,118,201,121,198,123,195,126,191,129,189,131,185,135,184,136,180,140,178,143,176,147,174,151,171,155,171,157,168,162,167,165,166,170,166,174,165,179,165,185,165,188,165,192,165,195,165,198,165,201,168,204,169,207,172,211,176,216,177,219,181,223,185,226,188,230,193,234,198,237,204,241,210,244,216,247,223,249,230,252,237,254,244,256,251,257,260,258,268,260,276,260,283,262,290,262,296,262,300,262,306,262,312,262,315,262,319,262,321,260,326,258,330,254,333,251,337,244,339,241,342,235,344,230,345,225,348,219,346,179,342,173,340,170,337,165,336,163,334,161,332,159,330,156,328,154,326,153,325,151,323,150,321,147,320,146,319,145,316,143,314,142,311,140,310,139,308,139,307,137,305,136,304,135,302,135,302,134,300,133,300,132,298,130,297,130,297,129,295,128,295,127,294,127,294,126,293,125,292,125,292,124,291,123,290,122,289,121,288,120,287,120,287,119,286,119
254,116,253,116,252,116,251,116,250,116,247,116,244,117,238,120,234,120,229,123,223,126,217,131,210,137,204,141,198,145,193,149,191,152,187,155,182,159,181,161,179,164,178,166,177,170,176,172,175,178,174,182,174,186,173,189,173,195,173,200,173,204,173,208,173,214,173,220,177,224,180,230,184,234,189,239,192,242,197,244,205,247,211,249,217,252,227,254,235,257,242,258,251,259,258,259,267,259,274,259,281,259,286,259,292,259,296,259,301,258,307,255,312,251,318,246,323,238,330,231,334,226,336,220,339,213,340,209,340,205,341,198,341,191,341,184,341,178,341,171,341,166,340,162,338,158,337,156,336,152,334,151,334,149,331,147,330,146,328,143,326,142,325,141,323,140,320,138,318,138,317,137,315,136,311,135,309,134,307,133,306,132,303,132,302,131,299,131,298,130,295,130,292,129,290,127,287,127,286,127,285,127,283,126,282,126,281,125,280,125,279,125,278,125,277,125,276,125,274,124,272,124,271,123,269,123,267,123,265,123,264,123,263,123,261,122,260,122,259,122,258,122,258,121,257,121,257,120
301,143,300,143,299,143,297,143,294,141,291,140,289,139,286,139,282,139,277,136,272,135,268,135,262,134,258,134,252,132,248,132,244,132,239,132,234,132,228,132,222,132,218,132,211,132,206,132,199,132,195,133,188,136,184,137,180,139,177,140,173,142,171,143,169,145,167,147,166,151,163,155,162,158,159,165,157,172,155,178,155,185,155,192,155,200,155,206,155,214,156,220,160,227,166,236,171,243,176,250,184,257,190,263,197,269,207,275,214,280,223,284,230,287,240,290,249,292,257,294,265,294,274,295,279,295,286,295,292,295,300,294,305,292,312,289,318,287,326,282,333,277,340,271,345,266,351,261,356,258,360,253,364,249,365,246,366,243,369,239,369,236,369,232,369,228,369,224,369,221,369,217,369,212,368,209,367,208,366,204,364,200,363,198,360,194,359,191,357,187,356,185,354,182,352,180,351,178,350,177,348,173,347,173,346,172,344,172,342,169,341,169,339,169,337,168,335,166,334,166,330,165,329,164,327,163,325,162,323,161,320,159,318,159,316,158,314,158,313,157,311,157,311,156,310,155,309,155,307,155,307,154,306,154,305,153,304,153,303,152,303,151,302,151,301,151,300,150,299,148,298,148,297,147
```

I want to save above file in to 2D double array based on coma separation.
for ex:

```
array[0][0]=289...
array[1][0]=254...
array[2][0]=301...
```

In above file each row have different column length.

Comment: Have you tried to do this on your own?

Comment: yes i tried i can read data into one dimensional string array, but can not convert to 2d double array

Comment: yes @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis

Comment: Basically... while not EOF { int i = 0; readline into string variable; assign String.Split(',') to array[i++] }

Comment: Oops.  The "int i = 0;" should be outside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, read the entire file line-by-line, so that you have each line as an individual string:

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Input.txt");
```

Then, create an array of int arrays. Make sure that it can hold as many int arrays as the number of lines you just read from the file, because this is where you'll be saving the results:

```
var result = new System.Int32[lines.Length][];
```

Now from each line you read, construct a string array by splitting that line and using the comma character as the separator:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var str = lines[i].Split(',');
```

Finally, turn that string array into an int array and store it:

```
    result[i] = str.Select(System.Int32.Parse).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: it is not saving rest of the columns after 0 in array, i need to save all the columns.

Comment: @user3544843 Can you be more specific? I'm running this in the debugger and I don't see how it fails to meet your description.  Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Select function is giving me the following error.
Error CS0012 The type 'Complex' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. demo DynamicTimeWarping C:\Users\Sohaib Omar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\demo DynamicTimeWarping\Program.cs 181

Comment: @user3544843 The code in my answer doesn't involve the `System.Numerics.Complex` type (or the `System.Numerics` assembly to begin with). Check if you have `System.Linq` referenced, it's all that's required.

Comment: i have referenced system.linq

Comment: @user3544843 That's weird. What if you change `int.Parse` to `x => int.Parse(x)`? Also, what's the error for `var i = 0`?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't answer this question but since one has already answered....

I would use Linq

```
var array = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(line => line.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      string file = @"C:\Path";
        using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = SR.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] Splitline = line.Split(',');
                // Do what you want with each array line
            }
        }
```